# monacaでhttpサービス

Tags: monaca, angularjs

monacaクラウドで試していて、なかなか解決しなくて困っております。
やりたいことはシンプルで、サーバーでの処理結果をJSONで受け取りたいだけです。
下記がコードの抜粋ですが、$http.get()で必ず失敗します。

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
　　・・・省略
　　$scope.proc = function() {
　　　　var url = 'https://(IPアドレス)/';
　　　　$http.get(url)
　　　　　　.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
　　　　　　　　// 成功
　　　　　　　　console.log('成功：' + JSON.stringify(arguments));
　　　　　　})
　　　　　　.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
　　　　　　　　// 失敗
　　　　　　　　console.log('失敗：' + JSON.stringify(arguments));
　　　　　　});
　　};
　　・・・省略
});
```

console.log()の内容は以下です。

> > 失敗：{"0":null,"1":0,"3":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],
> >     "url":"[https://(IPアドレス)/](https://(IP%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9)/)","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}}}」

何かHTTPヘッダを付加しないといけないでしょうか？

ちなみに、ブラウザ(safari)から同じURLで正常に受け取れるのは確認しました。
WebサーバーはIIS8、SSLは自己証明書(IISマネージャで作成)です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コードのミスか分からないので適当にクロスドメインであることを悪者にしてみます。

１．WhiteListPluginが弾いている
　　下記を追加して許可しましょう

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

２．サーバ側でクロスドメインの許可ヘッダを追加する
　　接続先のソースが何か分かりませんが、`htaccess`とかで許可すると
　　`Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
　　PHPなら(※他の出力より前に出力すること)
　　`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`
３．Chromeアプリなど環境に依存してる場合
　　上記１，２で大体解決するかと思いますが、
　　データの通信をJSONPで行うことで解決するかもしれません。

---

**他には……？**
サーバの処理が見えないのでGETリクエスト処理する段階でリクエストが空だとか
GETリクエストを受信できていないだとか、あるかもしれません。
サーバにデータが届いているか確認することが第一です。
もし、届いているのであれば、処理はうまくいっているのか？
返却値をサーバ内で出力するなどで確認できるかと思います。
そこまで確認して受信で失敗しているのでは？ってなります。

Comment: すごく詳しくありがとうございます！

結局、ご指摘の項目が全て当てはまりました。
・Windowsサーバー(IIS8)の環境の問題
・Chromeの問題
・クロスドメインの問題
・レスポンスされるJSONの文字のエスケープ問題

Comment: レンタルサーバー(Linux,Apache,共用SSL)があったのでそちらで試したところ、
あっさりGETを受信できたので、ようやく前進できました。
ただ、このレンタルサーバーからWindowsサーバーへGETは届くのに、
MonacaクラウドからWindowsサーバーは相変わらずGETが届かないので、
このレンタルサーバーを経由しているという状況です。

Comment: 手元にiPhoneがあるので試したところ
    Safariブラウザから → GETは届いた
    Monacaデバッガーから → GETは届かない
という状況でした。

Comment: 簡単にWindows環境を書いておきます。
  Windows8.1
  IIS8.5
  SSLはIIS8.5で作成した自己署名入証明書
      (いわゆるオレオレ)
  ポートマッピングでHTTPSをこのマシンへ設定
  Monacaクラウドもこのマシンで開いて作業しています。

Comment: 些細なことでもよいので「こういう可能性は？」というものがありましたら、
ぜひお願い致します。

Comment: ここのコメント、改行しても改行で表示されないですね。
なのでいくつかに分けて投稿しました。
申し訳ありません。

Comment: MonacaデバッガはSSL通信のポートを許可していなかった気がします。ビルドして試してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: レンタルサーバーへのSSL通信は、MonacaでもMonacaデバッガでもできています。

Comment: 解決しました。いわゆるオレオレの証明書は使わない方がよいですね。セキュリティに悩まされましたが、得るものも多かった1週間でした。Myaku様、ありがとうございました。